# Why is my removeEventListener not working? Looked through other posts, can't find an answer

Tags: javascript, frontend, click, logic, event-listener

This is a function where you click on a character and it heals them by the amount specified in the switch. I need the listener to trigger only one time per function call but the removal doesn't seem to be doing anything. As in you can just keep clicking and it keeps going through the switch. I've tested and ensured that the function itself is only being called once so I have no idea what's going on here. Tried removing the listener like document.removeEventListener('click', addAllyTargets) as well, no change. Angels_Grace_Part2() is purely imagery/text and has nothing to do with the listener.

```
var ally_targets = []
//make the list of targets
function makeAllyTargets() {
  let maketargets = document.getElementsByClassName('ally_img')
  for (let i = 0; i < maketargets.length; i++) {
    ally_targets.push(maketargets[i])
  };
};

var amt_healed;

function Angels_Grace() { //moderate healing spell on one ally
  makeAllyTargets();
  for (let i = 0; i < ally_targets.length; i++) {
    //add the listener to each target
    ally_targets[i].addEventListener('click', function addAllyTargets() {
      //amt healed is 55% of the target's max. 
      const selected_ally = ally_targets.indexOf(this);
      switch (selected_ally) {
        case 0: //knight
          amt_healed = 303;
          //ensure it doesn't go over max
          if (warrior_hp.value + amt_healed > 550) {
            Angels_Grace_Part2()
            warrior_hp.value = 550;

          } else {
            Angels_Grace_Part2()
            warrior_hp.value += amt_healed;
          };
          //remove the listener
          ally_targets[i].removeEventListener('click', addAllyTargets)
          break;
          //the other cases follow the same logic

        default:
          console.log("heal switch - shits fucked")
          break;
      };
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: You're calling `makeAllyTargets()` before it's defined, and even then, it's defined within the addEventListener() call, so I doubt you can access it from outside of that.
I think you'd need to define it outside of the addEventListener() statement, before you ever call it in `Angels_Grace()`.

Comment: @mykaf You're confusing `makeAllyTargets` with `addAllyTargets`.

Comment: I would try defining your `addAllyTargets` function outside of the event listener calls and just reference it by name in the event listener calls. As you have it defined in your example (inline/sort of anonymously) it's scoped to only the event listener calls. In other words - when you go to call removeEventListener, it doesn't know what `addAllyTargets` is, because when you added it with addEventListener you created the function inline and thus, scoped it only to that addEventListener handler.

Comment: Note that the change @jamauss suggests means you can't use `ally_targets[i]` inside the event listener.  But you can use `event.currentTarget` or `this` to get the target of the event.

Comment: @jamauss Why is scoping the problem? `addAllyTargets` is scoped to that callback function, but it should refer to the same function instance that was added with `addEventListener()` on that array element. This is a case where a name for an inline function expression should be useful.

Comment: @Barmar I think it's because in order to refer to a function by name like it is being done in that code example, it would have to be part of the global scope, which it wouldn't be with the way it's created. When he refers to `addAllyTargets` in the `removeEventListener` call, he's still inside the function itself.

Comment: @jamauss It would only have to be in the global scope if the call to `removeEventListener` were in the global scope. But the remove call is in the same scope as the definition, so it should work.

Comment: Have you tried using the once option?  `.addEventListener('click', handler(){...}, {once:true});`

Answer (score 0):

I went overboard in my answer.
There were a lot of things going on in your code that, in my opinion, could have been made simpler.

And so rather than go into a deep explanation as to why, I offer this for your consideration.

```js
function AngelsGrace(event) {
  //amt healed is 55% of the target's max. 
  let ds = event.target.dataset;
  let hp = +ds.hp;
  let maxHp = +ds.maxHp;
  let healingRate = +ds.healingRate;
  let amtHealed = maxHp * healingRate;
  let excessiveHealing = hp + amtHealed > maxHp;

  if (excessiveHealing)
    amtHealed = maxHp - hp;

  ds.hp = hp + amtHealed;

  if (amtHealed) {
    console.log(`${ds.class} hp was ${hp}. Healed for ${amtHealed}, now ${ds.hp}/${maxHp}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${ds.class} is at Full Health`);
  }

  console.log("casting Angels_Grace_Part2()");
  event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("angels-grace");

}


function CastAngelsGrace() { //moderate healing spell on one ally
  var oneTimeOnly = {
    once: true
  };

  let htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('ally_img');

  for (const tgt of htmlCollection) {
    tgt.addEventListener('click', AngelsGrace, oneTimeOnly)
    tgt.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("angels-grace");
  };
}
```

```css
.character {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 10px;
}

.ally_img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

.spell-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.spell-container:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.spell-container.angels-grace:after {
  content: "AG";
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="character">
  <image src="https://picsum.photos/id/718/200" class="ally_img" 
    data-class="knight" 
    data-healing-class="warrior" 
    data-healing-rate="0.55" 
    data-max-hp="1000" 
    data-hp="200" />
  <span class="spell-container"></span>
</div>
<div class="character">
  <image src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200" class="ally_img" 
    data-class="rogue" 
    data-healing-class="sneaky" 
    data-healing-rate="0.35" 
    data-max-hp="500" 
    data-hp="100" />
  <span class="spell-container"></span>
</div>

<button onclick="CastAngelsGrace()">Cast Angel Grace</button>
```

Comment: this is doing the same thing though. It's allowing multiple casts with only one button press. When I tried it in my actual code it gave me an "event is undefined" too and I don't know jquery so I can't really try and fix it

Comment: There is no jQuery here. If you look at the call to `addEventListener()` I'm supplying the options object, `oneTimeOnly`, as the third parameter.  This causes the event listener to be automatically removed once used, so no need for a call to `removeEventListener()`

Comment: Also, I took some liberties with game logic that manages the healing.  I added `data-*` attributes to each `.ally_img` that this function call uses to pull in parameters used by the function.